# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup on Wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am new to python and trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract all the train Stations Names on [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Singapore_MRT_stations) from the third column of the wikitable.
i have tried the code below but it seems to return every row of cells as 1 group of information

```
contentTable  = soup.find('table', { "class" : "wikitable"})
cols  = contentTable.find_all('td')
for col in cols:
    soup.find_all("a")
    print(col.get_text())
```

output as below representing 1 row from the table:

```
CG2 
TE [a]
Changi Airport
樟宜机场
சாங்கி விமானநிலையம்
8 February 2002
Changi Airport

CGA
Changi
Singapore Changi Airport,  Changi Airport PTB2 Bus Terminal
```

expected dataframe column *Station Names* :

```
Station Names
Jurong East
Bukit Batok
etc...
```

can someone teach me how to code this correctly?
Thank you!

Comment: try `contentTable.select('td:nth-child(3)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is just simply printing the text contents of each 'td' tag on the wikitable.

Try this instead:

```
contentTable = soup.find('table', {"class": "wikitable"})
trs = contentTable.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    for td in tds:
        if tds.index(td) == 2:
            print(td.get_text())
```

First it scrapes each row, finds each 'td'-tag on that row, and prints out its contents if it's the third 'td'-tag on the said row.

Comment: this is logical enough to understand for a starter!
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url to be scrape
URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Singapore_MRT_stations"

PAGE = requests.get(URL)

# get HTML content
SOUP = BeautifulSoup(PAGE.content, 'lxml')  # lxml is faster then html.parser

contentTable = SOUP.find('table', {"class": "wikitable"})

rows = contentTable.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
    columns = tr.find_all('td')
    for index, td in enumerate(columns):
        if index == 2:
            print(td.text)
```

Comment: thank you very much! your solution can be understood too

Comment: @Wavers you can upvote answer so, others might help it out.

Comment: I tried, will need to level up before system allow me to